# dismissModalView doesn't respond to touches

Tags: iphone

in MyAppDelegate, when a button is pressed it presents a modal view:

```
- (void) showInfoPanel:(id)sender {
```

infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *infoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 infoNavController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
 [window addSubview:infoNavController.view];
 [infoNavController presentModalViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];

}

in InfoViewController i have to dismiss the modal view:

```
- (void) exitInfoPanel:(id)sender {

 [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

although it works, the MyAppDelegate window doesn't respond to touches anymore.

instead in the InfoViewController if:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

It respond to touches but I lose the animation of dismissing the modal view.

What I am doing wrong, why it doesn't respond to touches when the modalview is dismissed? ?

thanks